# Error "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null at generateTable"

Tags: javascript

Can someone please shine some light on my this error is tossed? `outputTable` is properly referenced, and my JS file with the array `countries` is properly formatted.

I reckon I am appending erroneously, but I have tried all that I can.

PS if youre going to downvote, at least please tell me how to improve my questions in the future. I couldnt find a different question that exists already that matches my issue.

```
window.onload = generateTable();

function generateTable() {
    // get the reference for the body
    var outputTable = document.getElementById('outputTable');
    // revoke existing Body element
    if (outputTable) {
        outputTable.removeChild(outputTable);
    }
    // creates a <tbody> element
    var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
    // creating all table rows
    for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        // creates a table row
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        // create table column for flag
        var colFlag = document.createElement('td');
        //create image element in flag column
        var flag = document.createElement('img');
        flag.src = 'flags/' + countries[i].Code.toLowerCase() + '.png';
        flag.alt = countries[i].Code;
        row.appendChild(colFlag);
        //append flag to flag column
        colFlag.appendChild(flag);
        // create table column for Code
        var colCode = document.createElement('td');
        //append code to code column
        colCode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(countries[i].Code));
        row.appendChild(colCode);
        // create table column for country //**ENGLISH */
        var colCountry = document.createElement('td');
        colCountry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(countries[i].Name.English));
        row.appendChild(colCountry);
        // create table column for continent
        var colCont = document.createElement('td');
        colCont.appendChild(document.createTextNode(countries[i].Continent));
        row.appendChild(colCont);
        // create table column for area
        var colArea = document.createElement('td');
        colArea.appendChild(document.createTextNode(countries[i].AreaInKm2));
        row.appendChild(colArea);
        // create table column for population
        var colPop = document.createElement('td');
        colPop.appendChild(document.createTextNode(countries[i].Population));
        row.appendChild(colPop);
        // create table column for capital of country
        var colCap = document.createElement('td');
        colCap.appendChild(document.createTextNode(countries[i].Capital));
        row.appendChild(colCap);
        // attach columns to row
        tableBody.appendChild(row);
        outputTable.appendChild(tableBody);
    }
    // add the row to the end of the table body
    document.body.appendChild(outputTable);
}
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on? What did the debugger tell you? Where's the [mcve]?

Comment: `window.onload = generateTable();` is equivalent to `generateTable(); window.onload = undefined;` because your function returns nothing.

Comment: `window.onload = generateTable();` -> `window.onload = generateTable;`

Comment: @melpomene The debugger says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null at generateTable (myscript.js:52) at myscript.js:1 ; generateTable @ myscript.js:52 ; (anonymous) @ myscript.js:1`

Comment: `outputTable` is `null` because the function is executed before the DOM is ready

Comment: @HarryHawke So what's line 52?